# Robust panel data regression

Tags: panel-data, random-effects-model, outliers, fixed-effects-model

I have to improve my panel data analysis by detecting outliers. I already tried by removing them manually. Do you know some function running robust fixed effect or random effect model?
There is `lmrob` but it refers just to linear model.
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Have you looked into quantile regression (`quantreg::rq` with `tau=0.5` for the median) or proportional odds (`rms::orm`)?

Comment: @Dave Thank you, i will deepen these functions. Can i run them also with a panel structure of the data?

Comment: Quantile regression should not present any issues for the panel structure except that the particular software package `quantreg` might not support it. All the quantile regression does is use a different loss function. I suspect that proportional odds will handle the panel data just fine, but I am newer to that method and have less confidence in my assessment.

Comment: @Dave I just found out a function ```rqpd : : rqpd```  that run quantile regression for panel data, in case you'll need it in a future research